# Which one is better for drag sign

Tags: icons, drag-n-drop, symbols

I have checked some websites and found these two signs as drag symbol:

[image: drag signs]

Which one is better?

Comment: You really should test this with your users to which they understand (or if they need something altogether different)

Answer (score 6):

Before reading your question, I saw an image with a menu and a second image with two lines.

I think that not just the number of lines influences, but also the location.

[image]

But I still thinking the three lines looks like a hamburger menu.

The standard for dragging is the dotted line, and in this case the number of lines or direction is not relevant.

[image: dotted lines]

Answer (score 2):

Hamburger, used for opening/closing a site's navigational structure springs to mind first. They are identical to your example, usually seen with three lines, but now, with minimalism as important as ever, they are often seen only on two lines like your second example. Honestly, I'd avoid anything that could be misinterpreted. In a way, the more obvious the better.